# Is it recommended that my GF mentions she knows me in her application process?

Tags: applications, relationships, netherlands

My girlfriend is going to apply to a position at the company where I work, because of genuine reasons (she fits certainly well in the position). She knows some stuffs about the company business because I really love to work there, but now we are wondering how beneficial is to mention that we are involved in her application.

Are there any benefits/drawbacks for doing this? Are there any Potential problems if we do not?

Comment: If she were to get the position, would she be working with you at all? Or is it in a completely separate part of the company?

Comment: Assuming a relationship is allowed (see Thomas Owens' answer), you should probably be submitting her resume as a referral. It will drastically increase her likelihood of progressing as a candidate.

Answer (score 10):

First, are there any company policies against relationships with coworkers? I'm not sure how it is in the Netherlands, but in the US it ranges from the company doesn't care to rules about being in the same reporting chain to forbidding it entirely. You can consult with HR about this.

If your company forbids it, then not only should not you not mention your relationship, she probably shouldn't apply. There would likely be consequences for lying to your management.

Second, does your company offer referral bonuses? If so, you should consider referring her to the position. Sometimes, referrals get some extra weight in terms of coming in for interviews over candidates that apply cold. You may also get a bonus of some kind if she gets the job and works for long enough.

If it's not against policy, it's probably more effective to mention that you know each other and explain your relationship.

Third, you need to consider your relationship. How stable is it? If you were to end your relationship, would you both be OK seeing each other in the office nearly every day? Even if your relationship is good, would you both be OK with the drastic increase in time spent together?

Only HR can answer the first one. Only you two can answer the third.

Comment: I would add that the HR manual often answers this question. Check it before asking the question to HR.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any benefits/drawbacks for doing this?

As always, it depends.

First, check that your company has no prohibitions about girlfriends/partners working within the same company (or perhaps the same company unit).

If not, one benefit would be your acting as a good internal reference. In some companies you could even earn a referral bonus.

A potential drawback would be that - even if permitted - a hiring manager might not want to get into the middle of a situation that could affect two workers' performance. You might be a distraction to each other. And if the relationship goes sour, friction at work might cause performance issues.

> Are there any Potential problems if we do not?

Again, it likely depends on company policy.

Going against company policy can sometimes be cause for dismissal.